# Rendered video has no audio

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

I am using Blender to edit some video captures from OBS, and I am hoping to make some letsplay videos. Currently, I am making a "splash screen" of sorts where I have game music playing over a intro image. I imported a clip of gameplay that contained the music into Blender, and deleted the video strip and was left with just the audio strip. I then imported my titlecard image, set the frame count, added intro and outro fades, all good. Playing the video back in the editor, it all looks and sounds just like I want it to.

However, when I render the video using Render > Render Animation, my computer runs through the render and outputs the video file in the correct folder. When I play the video file with VLC, it has no audio. I have made sure volume controls are up to their highest setting and my speakers are turned all the way up.

I have looked through a few similar questions, and made sure I had the right settings but I am still getting no audio in my final render. Attached is a screenshot of my settings. Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

[image]